# What types are propositions?

Tags: coq, homotopy-type-theory, calculus-of-constructions

In the [propositions-as-types paradigm](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/propositions+as+types), we are still faced with the question : what types are propositions ? I currently know 3 different answers :

- Coq's sort `Prop` and its typing rule that asserts it is closed under products indexed by abtirary types
  $$\frac{A : \mathsf{Type}_i \qquad x : A \vdash B(x) : \mathsf{Prop}}
       {\prod_{x : A} B(x) : \mathsf{Prop}}$$
- HoTT's `HProp`, which are types where all elements are equal, together with the `HProp` truncation `fun A:Type => ∥A∥`, which assigns an `HProp` to each type `A`.
- Coq's new `SProp`. As far as I understand, `SProp` is almost the same as `HProp`, but instead of explicit rewrites, the type checker will be happy to implicitely convert any element of an `SProp` into another. So I won't discuss `SProp` anymore here.

I see some common points between `Prop` and `HProp`, the main one being that Coq is compatible with the axiom of proof irrelevance, which asserts that all `Prop`s are `HProp`s. Also there is the similar guarded `match`. Coq accepts to `destruct` a proof of a `Prop` only when it is proving a `Prop`. Likewise, the recursion principle of the `HProp` truncation accepts to lift `∥A∥ -> B` into `A -> B`, only when `B` is an `HProp`. Another common point is seen via Coq's extraction mechanism : all proofs of `Prop`s will be discarded, because they map to singleton types.

However I don't clearly see how either of these definitions captures the concept of a proposition. A `HProp` makes some sense to me, because uniqueness allows to interpret inhabitants as mere proofs that the `HProp` is true. But then one can argue that a proposition does have different proofs, some being simpler than others for example. Or some using more or less axioms than others (constructive proofs versus classical proofs for instance). Concerning Coq's `Prop`, I understand that it is impredicative, but I don't think it explains enough. And why didn't Coq take proof irrelevance as a hard typing rule (where 2 proofs are the same `Prop` would be judgementally equal, rather than propositionally equal) ? I think it would be compatible with HoTT, if we redefine `eq` in sort `Type` rather than `Prop`.

Part of the answer might come from the function extensionality axiom. If it is not there, then it is very hard to prove that a type is a `HProp`. So Coq's `Prop` might be a way to handle propositions without assuming funext. For instance, the closure of `HProp` by the `forall` quantifier needs funext, so `Prop`'s typing rule might be seen as an instance of funext.

Are there other definitions of propositional types ?

Comment: I think you are interpreting the name Prop too literally. Agda still can be interpreted using Curry Howard, but until recently didn't have a Prop type.

Comment: Minor quibble: Coq's `Prop` does not "collapse all the `Type_i`" because that would mean that it somehow makes them all equal. The correct phrase is "`Prop` is closed under products indexed by abtirary types".

Comment: @AndrejBauer quibble rephrased

Comment: One of the reasons for Coq's Prop is to have a clear separation between programs and their specification (in Prop). Everything in Prop can be erased at extraction. Here's an early paper.
https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82220294.pdf
I seem to recall that it was introduced in Christine's PhD-thesis.
https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00431825/document
( Sorry, no time to check this carefully right now.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original conception of propositions-as-types did not distinguish propositions and types at all: all types are propositions. Under this view, we may indeed speak of different proofs of a proposition.

One way to understand the differences between different conceptions of propositions-as-types is to view them as capturing different notions of provability and truth:

- If we say that `Prop = Type` then the elements of a proposition are the proofs, so we are capturing **proof constructions**. We may analyze proofs, and for instance distinguish them according to their size, the assumptions they use, etc.
- If we say that `Prop = HProp` then the elements of a proposition witness existence of proofs (but are not specific proofs), so we are capturing **provabillity**. We can still discern the reason for a proposition being true, because we can analyze the proof as lons as further constructions do not depend on the choice of proof.
- If we use the strict `SProp` which makes all proofs judgmentally equal (or simply erases proof altogether), then inside type theory we can never "discern" the reasons for a proposition being true, so this is more like **truth**, i.e., an external reason for something being the case. We do have soundness in the sense that type theory can express semantic entailment, e.g., if $p$ and $q$ are true then so is $p \land q$.

Coqs `Prop` is *conservative* in the sense that it makes no commitment as to what `Prop` is supposed to be. Coq is compatible with the view that `Prop` is an (impredicative) `Type`, as well as that it is something like `HProp`, or even just `bool`. This is a design decision.